# Error in sheets[["all"]] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, xlsx

I am new to R and want to ask a question on one example in xlsx.pdf.

Examples

```
## Not run:
file <- system.file("tests", "test_import.xlsx", package = "xlsx")
wb <- loadWorkbook(file)
sheets <- getSheets(wb)
sheet <- sheets[["all"]]
res <- readRows(sheet, startRow=3, endRow=7, startColumn=3, endColumn=10)
## End(Not run)
```

Problem:

```
 > sheet <- sheets[["all"]]
 Error in sheets[["all"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I dont know why ,and I just guessed the intention of the writer and replaced it with

```
> sheet <- sheets[9]
> sheet
[1] "all"
> res <- readRows(sheet, startRow=3, endRow=7, startColumn=3, endColumn=10)




Error in sheet$getRow : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

with no lunk, is there anyone please point out the problem with my doing? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. Both examples work for me.... Have you inspected your sheets object `str(sheets)`?

Comment: Thanks EDi!
Now it works for me as well:)